# Check if a value is in a string

Tags: excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula that will check each cell in Col A to see if it is contained anywhere in the cells in range B1:B3, then return a "true" or "false"

```
Col A            Col B                                           

ACAM-18QT-ANN    ACAM-50PLD-ANN,ACAM-18QT-ANN,ACAM-72PL-AQU,
ACAM-50PLD-ANN   POBIC-BR-SF,
ACPA-BR-SF       ACPA-BR-SF,ACPA-TB2-T-MAN,
```

Comment: Just went trough your history.  When you get a correct answer you should mark it as such.  Click the check mark by the answer.  It is something only the one who posted the question can do.  You should go back through your history and mark those answers that were correct as such.  People will stop helping if no feedback is given.

Comment: Thanks for the note. And the answer, it worked great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the SUMPRODUCT with SEARCH:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,$B$1:$B$3))*1)>0
```

[image]